# nested setTimeout not working properly in js

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

I have two functions:

```
function one(callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('one');
        callback(); 
    }, 3000);
}

function two(callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('two');
        callback();
    }, 2000);
}
```

when I call the functions like this:

```
one(two(()=> console.log('Done!')))
```

here is what it happens:

```
two
Done!
one
/Users/shahryarhaghighifard/Downloads/test/callback.js:68
    callback(); 
    ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
```

I see that while function 'one' is waiting for the timeout, the second function runs. but how? I am not calling it until after 3 seconds. do you know a way to make this work? I wan to output like this:

```
one
two 
done
```

I'll be happy if you can explain what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the second function and returning what it returns to the first. Since it returns nothing you are setting it to undefined.

Breaking up the code, you can see what is happening

```js
function one(callback) {
 setTimeout(function () {
 console.log('one');
 callback(); 
}, 3000);
}

function two(callback) {
setTimeout(function () {
console.log('two');
callback();
}, 2000);
}


var secondFunction = two(()=> console.log('Done!'));
console.log('secondFunction', secondFunction)
one(() => secondFunction);
```

How it should be

```js
function one(callback) {
 setTimeout(function () {
 console.log('one');
 callback(); 
}, 3000);
}

function two(callback) {
setTimeout(function () {
console.log('two');
callback();
}, 2000);
}

one(() => two(()=> console.log('Done!')))
```